# mysql problem with window function and alias

Tags: mysql, alias

`select *, row_number() over() as row_number from enrolled;`

when i write the query, the error occurs.
Error is syntax error(error 1064 (42000)).
Is there an error if the name of the window function and alias name are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `row_number` is a reserved keyword in MySQL 8.0. You must delimit it with back-ticks:

```
select *, row_number() over() as `row_number` from enrolled;
```

Alternatively, choose another column alias that is not a reserved keyword.

You can review the list of reserved keywords in MySQL 8.0 here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html